# Export Art Board View to JPG

Tags: export, sketch-app

Does anyone know how to export the art board view in Sketch to 1 image? Maybe a plugin exists?

I know how to export all the art boards to a pdf/jpg, but I am trying to keep the art board view and titles in tact on export.

I would like to be able to print this out on a large format printer when discussing the designs and flows with my team.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick I usually do is to create an extra artboard behind all the other artboards. Then you can export the new artboard, to your desired image format, which will then include all your content.

[image: Artboard export example from Sketch]

Comment: Great idea - that's really a clever solution.